# group checkboxes - how to uncheck the parent box if any child boxes are unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a script that groups child checkboxes under the parent checkboxes. It's working perfectly except that I want the parent checkbox **unchecked** if **any** child checkboxes are unchecked. If all childboxes are checked, then the parent checkbox should also be checked. How would I go about achieving this?

HTML:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Africa
<div class="content">
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="countries" class="childCheckBox" /> Algeria<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="countries" class="childCheckBox" /> Angola<br />
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> North America
<div class="content">
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="countries" class="childCheckBox" /> Canada<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="countries" class="childCheckBox" /> United States<br />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        //clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
        $(".parentCheckBox").click(
            function() {
                $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', this.checked);
            }
        );
        //clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
        $('.childCheckBox').click(
            function() {
                if ($(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
                    $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked', false);
                if (this.checked == true) {
                    var flag = true;
                    $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox').each(
                        function() {
                            if (this.checked == false)
                                flag = false;
                        }
                    );
                    $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked', flag);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRTMS/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the `length` of `childCheckBox` against the `length` of `:checked` ones:

```
$('input.parentCheckBox').prop('checked', $('input.childCheckBox').length === $('input.childCheckBox:checked').length);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRTMS/1/)

Comment: That works perfectly! I only have one issue. I have several sets of groups on the same page. It works on the 2nd group when re-checking all child boxes, so that the parent box is checked again, but it doesn't seem to work on the first one.

Comment: Yes, that works great! Thank you SO much! I will name my first-born after you :)